# About Ring of Gaussian integers modulo $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, gaussian-integers

I am studying ring of Gaussian integers modulo $n$ i.e. 
      $\mathbb Z_n[i] = \{ a+ bi \mid a, b \in \mathbb Z_n\}$
I saw that, it is field(hence Integral domain) whenever $n$ is prime number $p$ such that, $p ≡3 \pmod 4$.
Now, is same true when it is integral domain?
I means the ring of Gaussian integers modulo $n$ is an integral domain if and only if $n$ is prime $p$ such that, $p≡3\pmod4$?

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/n\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is *finite*.  So it is an integral domain if and only if it is a field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if $n$ is a rational integer, then $\mathbb{Z}[i]/n\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a field if and only if it is an integral domain, if and only if $n$ is a prime number which is $\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.  You can argue this using some elementary number theory and some results about unique factorization domains (as well as the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a unique factorization domain).  I'll show that if $n$ is *not* a prime number which is $3 \pmod{4}$, then that ring is not an integral domain.

Writing $n$ as a product of prime numbers and using the Chinese remainder theorem, we can reduce to the case where $n$ is a prime power, say $n = p^m$ for some $m \geq 1$.

Obviously, $\mathbb{Z}[i]/ p^m\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is not an integral domain when $m \geq 2$, since the image of $p$ there is nonzero and nilpotent.  So $m$ must be $1$.

If $p = 2$, then $\mathbb{Z}[i]/2\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is not an integral domain, because the images of $1+i$ and $1-i$ are nonzero, yet their product is.

If $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, then by a result from elementary number theory, $p$ can be written as a sum of two squares: $p  =a^2 + b^2$.  Actually, you can argue this directly from the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a UFD.  Then $p = (a+bi)(a-bi)$, and again the images of $a+bi$ and $a-bi$ in the quotient ring are nonzero, but their product is.